# Retrieve Document form CouchDb With DoctrineODM

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, couchdb, doctrine-odm

I'm Using this [bundle](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineCouchDBBundle) to manage my data

I'm able to create the document, but I can't retrieve them
I tried with

```
    $dm = $this->container->get('doctrine_couchdb.odm.default_document_manager');
    $users = $dm->getRepository('myGarageBundle:Utente')->find("781f1ea2e6281beb4ee9ff72b6054af2");
```

and this retrieve one document like this:

```
object(my\GarageBundle\CouchDocument\Utente)[303]
  private 'id' => string '781f1ea2e6281beb4ee9ff72b6054af2' (length=32)
  private 'name' => string 'foo' (length=7)
```

And this is ok.
But If i do

```
$users = $dm->getRepository('myGarageBundle:Utente')->findBy(array('name' => 'foo'));
```

I have got an empty Array.

My document in my couchDb is

```
{"_id":"781f1ea2e6281beb4ee9ff72b6054af2","_rev":"1-f89fc2372709de90ab5d1f6cfe6a8f47","type":"my.GarageBundle.CouchDocument.Utente","name":"foo"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [page](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-couchdb/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions)

> Querying by simple conditions only works for documents with indexed
>   fields.

you have to add this in your Entity

```
/**
 * @CouchDB\Index
 * @CouchDB\Field(type="string")
 */
private $name;
```

> The Doctrine persistence interfaces ship with a concept called
>   ObjectRepository that allows to query for any one or set of fields of
>   an object. Because CouchDB uses views for querying (comparable to
>   materialized views in relational databases) this functionality cannot
>   be achieved out of the box. Doctrine CouchDB could offer a view that
>   exposes every field of every document, but this view would only grow
>   into infinite size and most of the information would be useless.

If you want use method like `findAll()` you have to Index all you document:

```
<?php
/** @Document(indexed=true) */
class Person
{
    /**
     * @Index
     * @Field(type="string")
     */
    public $name;
}
```